# What is the difference between image segmentation and feature extraction in image processing?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, feature-extraction

I have read an article regarding Brain tumor segmentation.That article has some methods to segment the brain tumor cells from normal brain cells.Those methods are pre-processing,segmentation and feature extraction.But I couldn't understand,whats the difference between **segmentation and Feature extraction**.I googled it also,but still I didn't understand.Can anyone please explain the basic concept of this methods?

Answer (score 3):

Segmentation is usually understood as the decomposition of a whole into parts. In particular, decomposing or partitioning an image into homogeneous regions.

Feature extraction is a broader concept, which can be described as finding areas with specific properties, such as corners, but it can also be any set of measurements, be them scalar, vector or other. Those features are commonly used for pattern recognition and classification.

A typical processing scheme could be to segment out cells from the image, then characterizing their shape by means of, say edge smoothness features, and telling normal from ill cells.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Image Segmentation vs. Feature Localization • Image Segmentation: If R is a segmented region,
1. R is usually connected; all pixels in R are connected (8- connected or 4-connected).
2. Ri \ Rj =  , i 6= j; regions are disjoint.
3. [ni=1Ri = I, where I is the entire image; the segmentation
is complete.

• Feature Localization: a coarse localization of image fea- tures based on proximity and compactness – more e↵ective than Image Segmentation.

Answer (score 0):

Feature extraction is a prerequisite for image segmentation. 
When you face a project for segmenting a particular shape or structure in an image, one of the procedure to be applied is to extract the relevant features for that region so that you can differentiate it from other region. 
A simple and basic features which are commonly used in image segmentation could be intensity. So you can make different groups of structure based on the intensity they show in the image. 
Feature extraction is used for classification and relevant and significant features are used for labeling different classed inside an image.